# Conditionally formatting cells based on a row cell and a column header

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a sheet of dates and generic numbers something like this:

```
            Winner  2  4  7  12  23  54  77
Date 1        4        X
Date 2        23                  X
Date 3        12             X
```

I have figured out how to do conditional formatting to highlight the cell where the X is, buy putting a formula into every cell. What I am looking for is a mass formula that will look a the Winner cell and then match to the column header and highlight the appropriate cell.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only possible but with a delightfully easy formula, given your layout. Please try selecting the relevant range (if `Winner` is in B1, something like B2:I100),  Format - Conditional formatting..., Custom formula is and:

```
=$B2=C$1
```

with formatting of your choice and <kbd>Done</kbd>.

This does no rely on the cells containing an `X` - they could be empty.

Comment: Is it correct to say this breaks if the columns are re-ordered?